# Plotting position="identity" geom_col in ggplot2 - some series hiding behind others i.e. not visible

Tags: r, ggplot2, identity, geom-col

I'm trying to plot an annual time series in bar-chart format.

I have 7 sets of yearly data, and they are in a set order (so, the same dataset has the lowest value each year, and the same dataset is highest value each year)

I can plot it as a line graph and all looks well...

But when I plot it as a stacked bar graph, the draw order is meaning some bars and not visible. I don't for the life of me know how to override this. I've tried factor and levels and can't crack it.

If I plot as position="dodge" I can see that the earlier few in the group are smaller, so they are the ones that are 'behind' (i.e. invisible) when I use position="identity".

Is there a way of sorting large to small when plotting position="identity" ?

This code creates a similar dataframe to the first few lines of mine:

```
temp2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:70, 5, 14))
colnames(temp2) <- c("FY", "B", "L1", "L2", "L3", "L4", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", 
                     "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4")
temp2$FY <- 1976:1980
temp2$B <- c(800, 935, 650, 850, 650)
temp2$L1 <- temp2$B * 1.0149
temp2$L2 <- temp2$B * 1.0161
temp2$L3 <- temp2$B * 1.0191
temp2$L4 <- temp2$B * 1.0269
temp2$H1 <- temp2$B * 0.9323
temp2$H2 <- temp2$B * 0.9269
temp2$H3 <- temp2$B * 0.9135
temp2$H4 <- temp2$B * 0.8787
temp2$M1 <- temp2$B * 0.9867
temp2$M2 <- temp2$B * 0.9856
temp2$M3 <- temp2$B * 0.9827
temp2$M4 <- temp2$B * 0.9754
temp2 <- gather(temp2, Type, Rain, 
               B:H4, factor_key=TRUE)
temp2 <- ddply(temp2, .(FY, Type), summarise,
               Rain = sum(Rain, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Then if i do:

```
ggplot(temp2, aes(x=FY, y=Rain, colour=Type)) + geom_line()
```

... I get a normal line graph where you can see all the series.
But, if i do:

```
ggplot(temp2, aes(x=FY, y=Rain, fill=Type)) + geom_col(position="identity")
```

... then some of the bars are hidden behind the other bars.

```
ggplot(temp2, aes(x=FY, y=Rain, fill=Type)) + geom_col(position="dodge")
```

... shows that the 2nd 3rd 4th and 5th bars are routinely higher than the first, but the last 8 are lower. I need to somehow reorder my data by sorting it by the value in "Type" to this predefined order I have worked out from a different dataframe.

Hope that is clear.

Edit:
(this is using my full dataset but hopefully you get the gist)
[position="dodge"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AkUA.png)

Its clear that there are 7 series per "bundle".

But in position="identity" only 5 show up. Something about the outline of each graph maybe interfering with the very small difference between series?
[position="identity"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bkgr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forcats::fct_reorder()` to order values by `Rain`. This only works where `Type` values are in the same relative order in `Year`. This can best be seen in the following dodged graph.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

ggplot(temp2, aes(x = FY, y = Rain,
                  fill = fct_reorder(Type, Rain),
                  colour = fct_reorder(Type, Rain))) + 
  geom_col(position="identity")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(temp2, aes(x = FY, y = Rain, fill = fct_reorder(Type, Rain))) + 
  geom_col(position="dodge")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I can see that that works, but its not *quite* right when putting it into "identity". Now I'm wondering whether its because theres a very thin outline around each graph and that outline is bigger than the difference between two series.. I'll put some pictures in an edit

Comment: Yes columns have fill and colour arguments: colour is the outline or edge colour, fill is the fill colour. I have updated the answer to make the edge colour the same as the fill colour, Not sure there is a noticeable difference. As you say it seems that the proximity of values precludes visual separation at the scale of the graph.

Comment: Thanks yeah it must be the tiny line which is obscuring a couple of them from "identity" view. That fct_reorder code is exactly what I was after thanks for that. Is there a way of manually achieving that? (where say, not every time step is in the same order when ranked by Rain but where you want to specify what the plot order should be in the case of position="dodge")

Comment: Does the above answer the question? Do you have a data set which reflects the question in the comment? I would suggest this is posted as a new question with a relevant minimal reproducible example.

Comment: alright ill put in a new question at some point thanks for your help again